Youtube Data API v3 Captions - Download broken
After trying to get download SRT files from our videos via this API for 2 days, I think there is something broken with the captions API.
So to keep things as simple as possible, we tried getting it working just using the API explorer on :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download
But even here, I get a 404 error.
Our setup:

We are the channel owner, we are only trying to get our own subtitles/captions
We have a valid API key
We are using oAuth
We are retrieving the captionID using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/?videoId=xxAx0kOOAo8&key=XXXXXXX
Here's a sample caption id we are using for the query : AUieDaaebuQ4e7334VHqXqIIEiYfJI7IQAkJp0U6tO_7PSv0dao

Have tried multiple iterations of including and not including the tlang and tfmt values.
I can feed the videoID into a 3rd party captions downloader and it works instantly, so there's defintely a file there.
Anyone got any ideas?

It's one of the undocumented changes. You can now only use the API unless you (see this ticket in Google issue tracker):

Own the video
The video owner has granted permission

Alternatively, you can use:

This Python script from another StackOverflow answer.
Or the good plain old yt-dlp


But I am an Manager on the channel, and when I register the oath, I select the actual Brand(owner) as the authorisor, but it still doesnt work?
Yes, we have also found those additional script to get around it, but I'd prefet just to use the official API if it works
